# Word 2010 macro to set protection read only not sticking

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, password-protection

I have a Word (2010) macro that breaks links ad sets protection to read only.

If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
        ActiveDocument.Unprotect Password:=""
    End If

```
Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Fields.Unlink
Selection.StartOf


ActiveDocument.Protect Password:="", NoReset:=False, Type:= _
    wdAllowOnlyReading, UseIRM:=False, EnforceStyleLock:=False
```

The document opens as form fields only and contains some checkboxes.
When I run the macro and save changes to the document, it re-opens as form fields only even though protection states read only when checked before saving.

Oddly, when I set protection to read only manually and save, the read only attribute sticks.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: How do you make your macro run when the document is opened? Can you confirm it's running? (by adding a `MsgBox` command, for example)?

Comment: try "Activedocument.Protect Type:=2" See: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237966(v=office.12).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237966(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The `NoReset:=False` option means that the form will open with form fields only... - in other words, it will remove whatever was in the form. If that is not what you wanted, you need to set `NoReset:=True`.

Comment: I have a button on a toolbar to run the macro.
Added messages to confirm form fields only (protection = 2) upon open and when the macro runs at the start of the code and also at the end which confirms read only (protection =3).
This all works fine.
Changing the NoReset to True did not work. Exact same results.

Comment: Code changes, if relevant.

     MsgBox ActiveDocument.ProtectionType


    If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
        ActiveDocument.Unprotect Password:=""
    End If

    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Fields.Unlink
    Selection.StartOf
    
    
    ActiveDocument.Protect Password:="", NoReset:=True, Type:= _
        wdAllowOnlyReading, UseIRM:=False, EnforceStyleLock:=False
        
    MsgBox ActiveDocument.ProtectionType

Comment: To make a document truly "read only" you must add a password, I think. Otherwise the best you can hope for is a "recommendation" to read only. The code you need would be `ActiveDocument.WritePassword = "your_password_here"` - which I found [here](http://forums.techguy.org/business-applications/64550-vba-save-word-read-only.html). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but no-go.
Entering a password into my code doesn't work.

Comment: Trying the link you provided works somewhat, but annoying.
It appears to set Windows security to read only. One can open the document and edit it, they just cannot save back to the original, they must save to a new name.

Not what I'm looking for. The original must be protected as is and barred from editing. The ability to edit and save to a different filename will not work.

Comment: If you cannot use a password, I am out of ideas... sorry!  Maybe someone else can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try This to make your Doc read only:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sPassword As String
sPassword = "YourPasswordHere"
.Protect NoReset:=True, _
Password:=sPassword, _
Type:=wdAllowOnlyReading
End With
End Sub
```

You can then unprotect the document through the developer tab using the password you enter in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test2()
If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType = wdNoProtection Then
ActiveDocument.Unprotect
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps you can add a little more detail to your answer? Maybe a little description on what you did to solve the problem.